# Creating on-demand, print-quality PDFs (preferably in Ruby if feasible)

Tags: ruby, pdf, pdf-generation

**Main-Question**

What's your fast and reliable (as in "stable") solution to create on-demand, newspaper-like (as in "using advanced layout or typesetting") PDFs out of an application on a Linux server?

Therefore: No, HTML2PDF is not the solution I'm looking for. ;-)

---

**Bonus-Question**

And if it's not Ruby-based: Is there a way to steer your solution out of a Rails application? Preferably over a webservice or a something-2-Ruby-bridge-kind-of-thing?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

**Update**

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780932) and the [rtex gem](http://github.com/bruce/rtex/tree/master) suggested there looks like what I'm looking for. I'll keep this question unanswered to look if there are other suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typesetting well is hard.

If you can't find a ruby typesetting library, you may want to look at running a background pdflatex.  LaTeX source is pretty easy to generate programmatically.

How useful this idea is will depend a bit on how complicated your documents are, and how much you care about  the quality of output.  If you have simple text only, and only want something a bit better than html, you probably have more options.

Answer (score 1):

[Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/) is designed for this type of thing, and it's under current development.

Comment: Do you know a real-world example where Prawn has been used in an environment as the one I described? I'm a bit unsure about how flexible Prawn is regarding to newspaper-like typesetting.

Comment: Prawn seems to be "alpha-level software". In other words: It's not an option to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

With php I've had great luck with FPDF.  I generate a few thousand high quality reports everyday with it.  Never misses a beat and is pretty quick.  With php running on a webserver, I imagein it wouldn't be too hard to setup ruby to feed the php page the data required to generate and then ruby pick up the result.

EDIT:  It looks like there is a port for Ruby.  http://zeropluszero.com/software/fpdf/